# facebook oauth dialog returns blank page

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to use dialog/OAuth to get the code parameter from Facebook in order to get the token
When I try to log in using generated URL, I get a blank page.

[image]

I'm using this code to generate the url

```
sprintf('https://www.facebook.com/v15.0/dialog/oauth?%s', http_build_query(array(
            'client_id' => self::FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            'state' => 'op=add-page',
            'scope' => 'pages_show_list,pages_manage_metadata,pages_read_engagement',
             'auth_type' => 'rerequest',
            'redirect_uri' => url(self::FACEBOOK_APP_REDIRECT_URI),


        )));
```

Url Example

```
https://www.facebook.com/v15.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=369956434515590&state=op%3Dadd-page&scope=pages_show_list&response_type=code&auth_type=rerequest&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2Fapi%2Ffacebook%2Fauth
```

how can I make the dialog appear for approval, so I can get the code parameter

Answer (score 4):

I just needed to add   the redirect url  in Valid OAuth Redirect URIs

1- go to Facebook Login for business
2- settings
3-  add the url in Valid OAuth Redirect URIs

I hope it will help someone

Comment: Does it not work for https://localhost:8000 ?

Comment: it only works for domains with HTTPS

Comment: Note: this option is only available in the "Facebook Login (for Business)" product. So, if you actually want to use (e.g.) the product "Marketing API" only, you still need to add the "Facebook Login" product to your app aswell to set the oauth callback urls there.

Comment: Nice +1!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I've added Redirect Url and it still doesn't work - blank page, the same as yours was. Any idea? Business account